# How to add background music in asp.net without bgsound and embed

Tags: asp.net

How to add background music when a website loads for the first time without using embed and bgsound.I am using visual studio 2010 and these two are not supported  in this.
I am developing website using master page and i want to use the code in master
page.
What is the best practice to to be able when I open my website and some music starts f               sometime.I am not much expert in .net with c#.So finding some problem in it.
If browser also matters?

```
 Regards,
 suparna
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add the following code anywhere in the body of your HTML document to embed a music file and play it automatically when a visitor browses your website.**

```
 <audio src="music/yoursongname.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></audio>
```

Change the "**src**" attribute so that it contains the path and filename of the music file that you want to embed.

*Note:* Add the "**loop**" attribute if you want the music file to play over and over

Comment: audio is also not supported in this